# Populating a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have an dictionary containing 2 objects with separate keys, and I want to populate a table view cell with each object respectively. So say for example my dictionary has  2 objects one with the key north and another object with the key south. Now I want the table view to have 2 cells one containing north and one containing south. How would I go about doing that? so far i tried the code below but that only overrides it.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *news = (NSMutableDictionary *)[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"frstDirection"]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"secDirection"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `textLabel` twice with two different values?

Comment: i was testing to see if it was accessing the dictionary correctly. i would comment one to see if the other one would appear.

Comment: So explain what's wrong with your code. What problem do you need solved in this code? You are getting row-specific data from `feeds`. That seems correct.

Comment: the code works fine but i want one cell to display the object with the key frstDirection and i want the other cell to display the object with the key secDirection

Comment: That makes no sense. If you have row-specific data in `feeds` then your values should be in the row specific data. Why is your data setup such that the data for row 0 contains values for both rows and the data for row 1 also contains values for both rows?

Comment: Sorry I am confused do you mean I should have 2 separate arrays to hold each direction respectively?

Comment: Your data should be split up so each object in `feeds` just has data for that one specific row. Right now the dictionary for both rows seems to have both keys. Both dictionaries should have one key for the direction. The value would be specific to the row.

Comment: put if condition with indexpath.row like

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you have only two objects, you simply can use this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *news = (NSMutableDictionary *)[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if(indexPath.row==0){
     [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"frstDirection"]];
}else if(indexPath.row==1){
    [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"secDirection"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put if condition , if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) then first direction else second direction. In this way you will alternate cells with first then second .

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are trying to set value for cell twice so every time last value you will get as uitableviewcell.

**So try following code before** [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"frstDirection"]];

```
NSMutableString *teststring = [NSMutableString string];
[teststring appendString:[news objectForKey:@"frstDirection"]];
[teststring appendString:[news objectForKey:@"secDirection"]];
[cell.textLabel setText:teststring];
```